# Display users bookings when they are logged in

Tags: python, django

I am hoping someone can help me with something, I am new to Django and am currently putting together a restaurant booking system application. I have a lot of what I want to do done already but what I now want is for all a users bookings to appear in a "My Bookings" page when they are logged into their accounts. I want to give people the option to edit or cancel bookings if needed.
Can anyone guide me in the right direction in terms of making just the users bookings appear when they log in?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user is authenticated in your view with `if request.user.is_authenticated` (docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users)), then if so you retrieve all of their bookings and display the bookings page to them. If not, you can redirect to the login page for example, or just the home page or whathever.